# .htaccess deny access to subdirectories from a certain domain

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have a server with a security flaw:

There's the main site `https://example.com` (on server `/var/www` folder)
Then there's an additional app (on server `/var/www/app/public`) that is configured to be on `https://app.example.com`.

So the app is also reachable via `https://example.com/app/public` (i'd like to change that)

I have also the problem that the whole app is saved on the server for the developer. Means also all resource files are stored on a public folder, for example `https://example.com/app/config/settings.php`

Now to fix this I thought I'd put a `.htaccess` into `https://example.com/app` with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/app$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://app.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This would redirect everything with the wrong URL (`example.com/app/`, `example.com/app/public`, `example.com/app/resources`, ...) to `https://app.example.com`.

But when testing it, it doesn't work. I've probably messed up the syntax. Not very experienced with `.htaccess`. Tried for an hour with a `.htaccess` tester but didn't succeed. Can you (1) tell me what I'm doing wrong with the `.htaccess` syntax and (2) tell me if this workaround with the `.htaccess` is more or less safe enough?

Comment: Don't use htaccess files and simply place the configuration directives in the htttpd.conf of the specific virtualhost entry for app.example.com and/or www.example.com - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when

Comment: thanks for your reply. i've modified the httpd (and httpd-ssl).conf and added 

`<Directory /var/www/app/>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny From All
</Directory>`

inside the <VirtualHost> of the domain example.com. It works!

Comment: `Order` and `Deny` directives are Apache 2.2 and formerly deprectaed. You should be using `Require all denied` on Apache 2.4+ instead.

Comment: ok, will do. thank you!